# call a custom directives function inside a controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so I have an example custom directives code

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
            directive('exampleDirective', ['version', function(version) {
             return {
                      link:function(scope,elm,attr) {
                         elm.on('click',function() {
                              alert("clicked element")
                         });
                      }
                    }
            }]);
```

and this is the markup html that I made

```
   <example-directive></example-directive>
   <button ng-click="click()">click me</button>
```

as you can see the button is outside the example-directive environment and as you can see the ng-click is defined and throw the click() function into controller.

my question is how can I get the alret("clicked element") from custom directive when I clicked the ng-click button in angularjs ?

Comment: You can't with what you have. You have two different scopes.

Comment: yap isolated scope on the custom directives if I'm not mistaken.. so there isn't another way with the approach that I wrote above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZw7RHNfV0RkUFe28tGr?p=preview)

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link:function(scope,elm,attr) {
       scope.clicky = function(){console.log('clicked')};
    }
  }
});
```

Since we aren't creating a new scope with the directive, both the scope referred in the linking function of the directive and the one inferred by `ng-click` (which is another directive that comes with angular) will be the same scope, in this case the `$rootScope`.

Note that you need to add `restrict: 'E'` for the directive to work on what you wrote. The default value for that is by attribute (E is for element name) so it would work without it if you had `<div example-directive />`

Comment: I tried your plunkr and the button is inside the directive container if I'm not mistaken.. well is there a way with my approach above ? because my project mockup is set to be like that..